# Rails jQuery autocomplete using coffescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I am trying to get auto complete to work using the jquery UI, but it doesn't seem to be triggered.

The hashtag.js.coffee is being loaded into the application.js.  There are no errors being thrown in the console either

**hashtag.js.coffee**

```
$('.swag_text_field').autocomplete
source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag hashtags_path, class: "search-form", remote: true do %>
            <div class="input-prepend input-append">
            <span class="add-on swag">#</span>

            <%= text_field_tag :hashtag, nil, class: "span4 swag_text_field", id:"appendedPrependedInput" %>

            <%= submit_tag "VS!", class: "btn add-on-right swag_button" %>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out coffee script is white space sensitive.

```
   jQuery ->
        $('.swag_text_field').autocomplete
            source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

Comment: worked like a magic , upvoted for it . But why it's so . can you explain it . i just made 1 indent/tab in my code and it worked ;(

Comment: the answer means that you should indent a tab space on line after the autocomplete method